# Swagger - spring fox - hide password

Tags: java, swagger-ui, password-protection, springfox

**Swagger - spring fox - hide password.**

In one of our API I need to return alphanumeric code after verifying user id and password.

We are using **springfox-swagger-ui-2.3.1**.I have a field "password" where I do not want to show password (instead i want to show "XXXX") when user types in swagger ui.

password is defined as @RequestParam(value = "password") String password.

any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: have you tried `@RequestParam(value = "password", type = "string",  format = "password")` to see if it supports swagger format?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately springfox does not provide support for `swagger-core`'s password format.

It was introduced in swagger-core 1.5.11 [#469](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/469)

Issue [#2366](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2366) is still open in springfox.

Answer (score 1):

To use password as a parameter type, you can simply override the format like this:

```
@ApiParam(value = "your password", type = "string", format = "password") 
@QueryParam(/* normal stuff */)
```

[hidden password for APiParam](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/469)

Answer (score 0):

Issue is fixed in 2020 release of 3.0.0

https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/3002

https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/3386